# Homotopy equivalences in pushout square with cofibration.

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory

> If following square is a pushout square, $g$ is a cofibration and $f$ is a homotopy equivalence then $i$ is also a homotopy equivalence.
>   $$
> \begin{matrix}
> A & \xrightarrow{f} & B \\
> \left\downarrow{g}\vphantom{\int}\right. & & \left\downarrow{h}\vphantom{\int}\right.\\
> C&  \xrightarrow{i} & D
> \end{matrix}
> $$

My idea was to take firstly the homotopy $H$ which makes $ f \circ \tilde f \simeq \mathrm{id}_B$ and then write down arrows $g \circ H(\square,t):B \to C$ and $\mathrm{id}_C:C\to C$ from universal property of push-out we'd obtain arrow $i_t:D\to C$ then we could "glue" homotopy equivalence between $i_1 \circ i \simeq \mathrm{id}_C$, by formula $\tilde H(c,t) = i_t(c)$ but we don't know whether it is continuous function in $t$. Is there any way to show that (this "induced" homotopy $\tilde H$ seems to be unique so intuition tells me that it is possible). And how to show existence of  $\tilde f \circ  f \simeq \mathrm{id}_A$ homotopy? I'd be grateful for hints and answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An answer to this is that the result required is a special case of the gluing theorem for homotopy equivalences discussed [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/96071/general-gluing-theorem-for-adjunction-spaces) and proved in [Topology and Groupoids](http://groupoids.org.uk/topgpds.html).  The relevant Chapter 7 on "Cofibrations" is available [here](http://groupoids.org.uk/pdffiles/TandGCh7.pdf).  This result was found, as explained there,  by generalising the proof that a homotopy equivalence of spaces induces an isomorphism of homotopy groups, and so the proof given there has the advantage of giving control of the homotopies involved.

Comment: Thank you for all the references.